# R: Filled Contour plot will not plot all of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, plot

So my colleague and I made a matrix of my data in R (Using pipes: Package dplyr, magrittr) and plotted it in a filled.contour plot. But for some reason it will not plot my final two points.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Here is my `dput`for my data set/matrix :

```
structure(list(AvgDepth = c(5L, 5L, 15L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 5L, 15L, 
25L, 35L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 5L, 15L, 
25L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 65L, 5L, 15L, 
25L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 65L, 75L, 5L, 15L, 25L, 35L, 45L, 55L, 65L, 
75L, 85L, 95L), AvgMaxDepth = c(5L, 15L, 15L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 75L, 
85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 
95L, 95L, 95L, 95L, 95L),  MiddleOldG = c(-0.010339548, 
-0.019087115, -0.013710817, -0.018843724, -0.016954714, -0.009270159, 
-0.021369483, -0.020470118, -0.020793118, -0.038538718, -0.014960888, 
-0.010406261, -0.014440231, -0.018794958, -0.020203279, -0.015599607, 
-0.017050242, -0.024199387, -0.025290379, -0.026409047, -0.023564188, 
-0.027233605, -0.031364833, -0.033557383, -0.036140136, -0.022472455, 
-0.011018529, -0.01468673, -0.022262797, -0.027657312, -0.026680228, 
-0.02738715, -0.025351831, -0.026051226, -0.021691668, -0.025787225, 
-0.018350888, -0.019350486, -0.018076008, -0.011645933, -0.005070788, 
-0.006843451, -0.001764863, -0.001371702, -0.002248032, -0.002476992, 
0.00325166, 0.004070139, 0.033053363, 0.022264692),  x = c(1, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), y = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("AvgDepth", "AvgMaxDepth", 
 "MiddleOldG", "x", "y"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Here's what the matrix looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6ngn.png

Here is the code

```
library(colorspace)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Descent<-read.csv(file.choose())

attach(Descent)

summary(Descent)

Descent %<>% mutate(x = (AvgDepth + 5)/10, y = (AvgMaxDepth + 5)/10)

z = matrix(NA, ncol = 10, nrow = 10)

z.middle = Descent %>% select(x, y, MiddleOldG) 

for (i in 1:nrow(z.middle))    z[z.middle[i,1],z.middle[i,2]] = z.middle[i,3]

filled.contour(x = seq(5, 95, by = 10), y = seq(5, 95, by = 10), z, color.palette=diverge_hsv, xlab="Depth (m)", ylab="Maximum Depth (m)", levels = pretty(c(-0.04,0.04),24))
```

But it won't plot the 9,10 and the 10,10 data points in the matrix

They should be in the top right corner of the plot, but they aren't.

[image: Filled.Contour]

Any ideas why it isn't plotting those last two points?

Here is the data set: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13BJQ9-EXr2wu5tZNqXSzdbg_cLUjVw65W7yAAwydf_8/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: If you look up `filled.contour` on SO you should find descriptions for the reasons behind your failure.

Comment: @42- I have been searching, with no result

Comment: I misread the question as saying you wanted to plot points inside filled.contour. Instead, the reason you are getting no attention is that people are not willing to attempt reproduction of your problen in the absence of data in a form that is easy to cut and paste. Nobody can import that image. Learn to post the results of `dput(Descent)` as an edit to your existing question.

Comment: Ok I will try that!

Thank you for the help

Comment: And now there is no `%<>%` function or object named 'viridis'. Please learn to test you code and data by restarting in a new session and running just the code with the data. It will help you spot missing library statements and syntactic errors.

Comment: %<>% Is a function from the dplyr and magrittr package.

viridis is simply a color package and I actually realized that is not the palette I showed in the picture.

I will update my code now with everything, sorry for the inconvenience.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally is is a "bad idea" to `attach` dataframes when you are then going to process them with hadleyverse functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `filled.contour` function needs 4 points to form a filled area. If you set adjacent points in the 9th column you then get the appropriate color in the upper right corner corresponding to the lower right "corner" of the matrix:

```
z[9:10,9] <- 0
filled.contour(x = seq(5, 95, by = 10), y = seq(5, 95, by = 10), z, 
                color.palette=diverge_hsv, xlab="Depth (m)", ylab="Maximum Depth (m)", 
                levels = pretty(c(-0.04,0.04),24))
```

[image]